# Deleting related data from 3 tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have three tables and they are related in some ways by connecting on specific IDs

The 3 tables are:

- Table `CMD` with `ID` as the key
- Table `CMI` with `MeteringID` as PK, and `ID` column referencing `CMIH.IntervalID` column
- Table `CMIH` with `IntervalID` as the key

I would like to delete data from `CMD`, `CMI` and `CMIH` tables. Where I can put let say CMD table has Date field to where CMD.Date is xyz... to filter down

This is my SQL statement:

```
select * 
from Table1 as CMD
join Table2 as CMI on CMD.id = CMI.MeteringID
join Table3 as CMIH on CMI.ID = CMIH.IntervalID
```

Thank you in advance everyone.

Comment: Perhaps you want ON DELETE CASCADE foreign keys?

Comment: kindly put 2, 3 rows of every table as example in question

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE *
FROM CMD
WHERE (ID = @ID)

DELETE *
FROM CMI
WHERE (MateringID = @ID)

DELETE * 
FROM CMIH
WHERE (IntervalID = @ID)
```

You can delete the data in these 3 tables by sending the @ID as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TSQL` to handle cascading deletion.

```
delete CMD
from Table1 as CMD
join Table2 as CMI on CMD.id = CMI.MeteringID
join Table3 as CMIH on CMI.ID = CMIH.IntervalID

delete from Table2 where MeteringID not in (select id from Table1)
delete from Table3 where IntervalID not in (select id from Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE *
FROM CMD
WHERE (ID = @ID)

DELETE * 
FROM CMIH
WHERE IntervalID in (select ID from FROM CMI
WHERE MateringID = @ID)

DELETE *
FROM CMI
WHERE (MateringID = @ID)
```

You can delete the data in these 3 tables by sending the @ID as a parameter.

Comment: You should highlight here the 1-line difference from mrtgd's answer and explain why